# how to create the partition from unallocated space

Tags: hard-drive

I have some free space in my Hard disk and i want to create it as a NTFS partition to able to detect in my Windows XP . I am completely new to Linux/Ubuntu .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open your terminal and type this

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

then click at unity dash and type as gparted . it will gives you gparted application icon , click it to open . it will prompt for your root password nothing but  login password(if you are singe user ) .

it will display you all the partitions and empty space of your HDD . Now right click at the unallocated/empty space . among the options click at NEW . then it will open the window . give the required size and type of the partition .

look at the image for more information . [image]

Comment: No problem, keep up the great answers! :)

Answer (score 0):

control panel, admin tools, then computer management.  Storage, disk management option.  You can shrink \ partition as you would like. in ubuntu you could use disk utility or fdisk to do this

Comment: This is the Windows-related method. Could you provide a Ubuntu-related one?

Comment: There is also the option of using Disk Utility instead of using Gparted even though the latter is most powerful.