# Question about Partitioning

Tags: installation, boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

I am looking to dual boot Windows 7 and Ubuntu 13.10. I have been using windows for work and school for over a year, and have about 100 gig of stored files (backed up of course) and some paid programs. Because of this, I really want my partitioning experience to go well. Unfortunately, I am running into a bit of an anomoly
When I load GPart, I see that my sda drive is unallocated

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/41fdU.jpg]

Whereas my sdb appears to contain all of the windows files and partitions, and make up my C: drive
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TySz4.png]

Is this going to be an issue, as all literature on dual boot installation references sda? How do I work around it?

System Info:
Lenovo IdeaPad Y570- 750GB HDD with 64GB SSD
Processor: Intel® Core™ i7-2670QM CPU @ 2.20GHz × 8

Comment: I'm sorry for my lack of knowledge. I am basically looking to shrink my C: drive to make room for Ubuntu, but ran into the problem of not recognizing my SSD. I am an absolute beginner in all of this, and am just looking for a solution that will not destroy all my files?

Answer (score 1):

See [my Web page on this problem.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/missing-parts/) In brief, either your partition table is damaged or there's leftover RAID data causing problems. In the first case, using [FixParts](http://www.rodsbooks.com/fixparts) can often (but not always) solve the problem. In the latter case, typing `sudo dmraid -E -r /dev/sda` should fix the problem -- but do this only if you're 100% positive that the disk is ***not*** legitimately configured for RAID.

Comment: Pardon my lack of Knowledge, but what is RAID? I will admit that I never set up or used the SSD, so could it possibly be the problem (It doesnt even show up in windows 7)

Comment: I just started reading up, and it appears that the SSD was never configured in the first place when I first set up the computer about 1.5 years ago. I assume that this is going to be problematic. Do you have any advice as to how to set it up without a total system reinstall?

Comment: If the disk has never been partitioned, see [this question and its answers.](http://askubuntu.com/questions/183959/partititoning-the-hard-drive-after-ubuntu-installation)