# Help with partitions (Probably rather simple but I need help)

Tags: partitioning

Ok so essentially I reduced the size in a partition in my hard drive. I am installing Lubuntu and need it for that.

Now it says that space is unusuable.

If you need more info, ask me.

Comment: what are you using to partition??

Comment: The Lubuntu installer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can install **Gparted** it can be done. But for that you will need terminal. Restart installation and select **Try Ubuntu** instead of install. And then:

Open your terminal and type this

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

then click at unity dash and type as gparted . it will gives you gparted application icon , click it to open . it will prompt for your root password nothing but  login password(if you are singe user ) .

it will display you all the partitions and empty space of your HDD . Now right click at the unallocated/empty space . among the options click at NEW . then it will open the window . give the required size and type of the partition .

look at the image for more information . [image]

Copied from [how to create the partition from unallocated space](https://askubuntu.com/questions/176187/how-to-create-the-partition-from-unallocated-space)